# Running Internet Explorer with selenium WebDriver.quit(); does not work

Tags: java, selenium

I am running the following code and the browser does not close.

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

 public class _getPageIE {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
      capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\WebDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      WebDriver ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

      ieDriver.manage().window().maximize();
      ieDriver.get("http://google.com");

      ieDriver.quit();
      System.out.println("end");
      }
 }
```

The Browser opens, then is maximized and the Google page is displayed. Then the System.out.printlin is executed and the program ends, but the browser remains open.

I am running Eclipse with Selenium 2.44 on Windows 8.1 64 bit with the 64 bit IEDriverServer.exe.

The Console output is as follows.

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.44.0.0
Listening on port 46733
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried the same exact code and it worked on my system. I am using IE9 on win 7, Can you check with  the same  IE version on your system?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback TheMuffinCoder.

Comment: I am also having problems with this editor in Stack Overflow - difficult to format comments.                                                                             Anyway I am running Internet Explorer 11 and Java 1.8.0_31